# Doubt in ajusted-for-chance cluster validation

Tags: clustering, validation

I'm reading some paper about external cluster validation with the terminology "adjusted for chance" like (https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07786 and [www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/15-627/15-627.pdf](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/15-627/15-627.pdf)) that I could not fully understand. So far, I think it is related to the expected value that introduces a certain change for several runs of the measure for the same clustering.

I would appreciate if someone explained this assumption is correct or if I have not understood yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjustment for chance is

`(score - estimate)/(optimum - estimate)`.

The estimate usually is analytical, not by sampling ,and not based on the evaluation subject, so it's the exact average from "throwing dices".

The resulting scores are well interpretable:

1. A value close to 0 is a result "as good as random"
2. A value close to 1 is close to optimal.
3. A value much less than 0 is worse than random, i.e. there is a pattern to how it is different.

Speaking of dices: a fair 6 sided dice has an estimated value of 3.5; "constant" unfair dices would yield adjusted for chance scores of `-1, -0.6, -0.2, +0.2, +0.6, +1`.

If you have the choice of an adjusted for chance score, **always use the adjusted version**. You lose nothing, but gain interpretability.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, so it's a kind of normalization?

Comment: is Adjustment equal to  Normalization? Any different?

Comment: Yes, adjustment for chance is a linear transformation used for a specific kind of normalization. Focused on 0 for random results (expected value) and 1 for optimum.